# how to show the string in line by line in Silverlight Datagrid label in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, silverlight-4.0

I am using silverlight Datagrid in side I have label where in Text need to shown as formated as stated below.

I have string = RTY, EER, RRR,SFG

I have to show in Sivlerlight Datagrid Label as

Result :

RTY,
EER,
RRR,
SFG,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after all my searching Here goes the Answer it's just as simple as that.

VB.Net :

Append the "& vbCrLf &" to the string where you want to break the line to Display Multiline Text in Textblock and Label controls.

Example :

```
"RTY"& vbCrLf &"EER"& vbCrLf &"RRR"& vbCrLf &"SFG
```

Result :

```
RTY

EER

RRR

SFG
```